# Graphical layout won't show my button background

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a button background described as follows in its own "custom_easy_but.xml" in a directory res/drawable as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/but_easy_p"
    android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/but_easy" />

</selector>
```

Then I have a layout called modeselect.xml which includes the following code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/easy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_easy_but"
    android:text="@string/Easy" />
```

then I have a set different sized images in files called but_easy.png and but_easy_p.png in separate directories res/drawable-large and res/drawable-normal. The code compiles, runs and displays exactly the right button background images on a variety of phones... but if I look at the file modeselect.xml using eclipse and switch to the "graphical layout" view, I do not see the background images at all, and underneath the graphical view I see

```
failed to parse file c:\blah\blah\res\drawable\custom_easy_but.xml
```

and

```
couldn't resolve resource @drawable/but_easy_p
```

How can it be that the real phones can sort out all the xml but eclipse can't?

Comment: At which screen size did you let display eclipse the screen? I even had a problem like this, then I saw that this was because I had opened the graphical editor with a device-screen where I had set no resources

Comment: Yes - that's it - just changed to a different device size for the eclipse view and it then worked. If you put your comment as an answer I will give you the green tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you have set the correct Screen size in the graphical Editor. If You had chosen a screen size, where You got no resources, Your layout will not be shown.